# Dispose() does not prevent out of memory exception

Tags: c#, dispose, out-of-memory

I have a huge log file where there are about 15 million lines. I have to port all these lines to Oracle database. Here's what I do to do that:

1. I read lines to a DataTable (Lines are separated by commas so that
   they form columns). I read the lines by StreamReader and put it in
   using so that it get's rid of it when it's done reading.
2. I put a counter that gets incremented by 1 every line read to the DataTable.
3. When that counter reaches 40.000 I import all the rows to the database with the help of OracleBulkCopy.
4. When importing is done I say:

   `bulkCopier.Dispose();

   dataTable.Dispose();`

However this does not help any how. In the task manager I see the memory usage growing until it becomes out of memory. Now my question is doesn't `Dispose()` method release the memory immediately? If it does, then why does the memory usage accumulate as if all the DataTable and OracleBulkCopy objects stay retaining the memory.

Comment: You're importing them into a `DataTable`.  So that `DataTable` is backed by a separate database?  What does the `DataTable` point to?

Comment: No; `Dispose()` does not release memory.

Comment: No, it's not backed by any physical table. It's just a temporary table to hold the log file data so that I can send it to OracleBulkCopy WriteToServer method as an argument

Comment: I think you are assuming the stream is the problem, and perhaps incorrectly. How large are these strings?  If they are being allocated on the LOH then you might be causing a lot of fragmentation. Use a profiler to see where the memory is allocated.

Comment: @Mike, if it's just in memory, why are you surprised you are running out of it when loading 15 million rows into it?

Comment: GC.Collect() may help in those situations, or compiling the application for 64-Bit. Although even on 32-Bit, the GC should automatically run if memory pressure gets too high. Maybe the objects are so big they go on the Large Object Heap?

Comment: Hmm,I think the stream reader is where I miss a point. The stream reader still uses the memory and it continues to grow because it does not begin from the scratch every time the counter hits 40.000. It just jumps to another process and then continues reading. And as it reads it consumes more and more memory

Comment: In this case, is there a way I can release the old stream reader and continue from the next (40001st) line but with a new stream reader object?

Comment: Get a memory profiler and use it to figure out what is holding on to the memory. There's no way for us to know what is happening on your machine.

Comment: The Garbage Collector might not immediatly clean up after you've disposed your objects. Have you tried to wait on GC.WaitForFullGCComplete(); until you start a new batch? Doubt it helps though, best is to profile it.

Comment: I followed @Eric Lippert and Ed S. advice and checked it with the profiler and it really is the stream reader which causes the problem.  Now I need to find a way to start from where I stopped with a new stream reader object. Thank you all guys.

Comment: If you are having memory issues then dump DataTable - it is a memory hog.   Collections have come so far in .NET.   I don't know about Oracle but in MSSQL I got the fastest uploads using TVP (Table Value Parameter) and I use them with a collection (HashTable) not a DataTable.   It is like a referse DataReader.  I parse some text files and load the words and load millions a night.   I parse on the main thread and then use a BackGround worker to load to SQL on another thread every 10,000 rows.

Comment: The name streamreader and nature of the methods would lead me to conclude it does not hold previous lines in memory.  As for DataTable that is one heavy weight beast - again dump it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dispose does not release the managed memory immediately.  Dispose releases any locks to unmanaged resources (such as memory) when you call dispose and has nothing to do with managed memory.

Your Datatable is all populated with managed objects in managed memory.  Calling .Dispose on it won't do much of anything.  You need to clear all of the data from the DataTable (there's a handy `Clear` method for doing that) which will allow the garbage collector to free up the memory at some point in time in the future when it feels like cleaning things up.

Using a profiler you can see where exactly all of the memory in your program is being kept.  It's quite likely that there are a number of other managed objects that you're holding onto references to, which is preventing them from being garbage collected.  This has nothing to do with `Dispose`.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, dispose signals the internal handles to be teared down. An object with a Dispose gets GC-d actually later.

If those are IDisposable, you should try using them in a using() block, according to docs that is what releases automatically after usage.

You can force GC collection with GC.Collect, but I do not think those objects are unfreed grabage, .NET is better then that.

Can you not create a minidump and check what gets stucked and why?

Answer (score 2):

> Now my question is doesn't Dispose() method release the memory
>   immediately?

Not necessarily. The only memory it will release is that amount allocated by unmanaged resources. It will have no effect on the managed heap.

What you need to do is make sure there are no references to these dangling `DataTable` instances. You may need to remove them from a collection or `null` out the variable references as needed.